# R-Common elements on all pairwise comparisons of elements of a vector

Tags: r, vector, comparison, pairwise

I have a vector in R, say c(2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4), and I want to build a square matrix of size n (the number of elements of the vector) that has a 1 if the element i of the vector has the same value of the element j , and 0 otherwise. In this example , the element [1,2] and [1,4] of the matrix must have a 1 because the first, second and fourth elements of the vector are the same.
Is there a way to do this ? A command or function to build ? Something with combinations ? I would like to avoid loops like for.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `outer` to create a square matrix by comparing each element of the `vector` with the other elements

```
+(outer(v1, v1, `==`))
```

---

Or use `sapply`

```
+(sapply(v1, `==`, v1))
```

Comment: Ok! Will check it tomorrow :-)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

This just came to my mind... Is this what you want?

```
a <- c(2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4)
mat <- a%*%t(a)

apply(mat, 2, function(x){as.integer((x/a)==a)})
```

Comment: Or `(mat/a == a) * 1`

Comment: @RichScriven haha of course, thanks. That makes me feel foolish, but hey, I posted this before my first coffee ;-)